# Azure or AWS for sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am currently evaluating where to set up a new Sitecore infrastructure for a client.  The client no longer want an on-premise set up.  I am looking into both Azure and AWS and was wondering if there is an advantage to using one over the other.  Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This question is not on topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore 9 is built with cloud first mindset and it is based (built around) Azure technologies. So, the simple and short Answer is go with Azure, it has many advantages.

Comment: It actually depends on whether PaaS or IaaS is going to be used - your answer is valid for PaaS. (In fact, when talking PaaS Azure is the only supported platform)